# boost::filter_iterator -- how would I do that with the STL?

Tags: c++, stl, boost, filter, iterator

I am passed an Iterator and I have to pass it on to another function -- but filtered so that certain elements are skipped (it's a range of pointers, and I want to filter out the NULL pointers).

I googled for "*stl filter iterator*" to see how to do this, and [boost::filter_iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/iterator/doc/filter_iterator.html) came up.

That looks nice and I could use it, but could I do that with the good old STL as well? Without copying the elements into a new container, of course.

I guess I'd have to create another iterator class that provides the necessary `begin()`, `end()` etc functions and does the filtering? So I'd exactly have to reimplement the `boost` `iterator_filter`...?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are correct; you would essentially be recreating the filter iterator yourself.
My advice would be to use Boost's filter_iterator. Boost has special status as c++'s most used external library; many c++ committee members have helped write libraries for boost. Its ubiquity essentially makes it almost-stl as is; there's really no reason to reinvent the wheel here.

Comment: I slightly disagree: boost can be cumbersome to install, and sometimes you don't want that extra dependency. I think the *real* reason one would not rewrite `filter_iterator` is that it is in fact quite difficult (and very cumbersome) to write correctly.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with rlbond. Don't reinvent the wheel and use Boost::filter_iterator. If you don't want to have all boost libraries in your project, you may want to consider using [boost.bcp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/tools/bcp/bcp.html) to extract exactly the ones you need.